# JQuery variable value in quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem putting variable value in quotes in Jquery:

for example:

I have a Html color code in variable color, which has a value #FFFF00. I vant to display variable value like this: "#FFFF00".

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
context.strokeStyle = "\"color\"";
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the variable directly.

```
context.strokeStyle = color;
```

and if you want to add quotes to it:

```
context.strokeStyle = "&quot;" + color + "&quot;";
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to display the string wrapped in quotes then simply use:

```
context.strokeStyle = '"' + color + '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the quotes.

```
context.strokeStyle = color;
```

Should do just fine.